Improving validation accuracy of an image sentiment identification system
I am trying to develop an image sentiment identification (to start with, only 2 sentiments - happy or sad) system through transfer learning by using InceptionResNetV2 as the base model. I have given the code below. (I got this approach for transfer learning from the book Deep Learning with Python by Chollet.)
I found InceptionResNetV2 to have the best validation accuracy for image classification based on the approach described by Marie Stephen Leo (How to Choose the Best Keras Pre-Trained Model for Image Classification | by Marie Stephen Leo | Towards Data Science).
However, the validation accuracy for sentiment identification is stuck at around 81%. I have tried multiple things, such as adding dropout, increasing the number of epochs, increasing/decreasing a number of nodes in the last layer between 64 and 512, curating the training/validation dataset, etc.
Please let me know how I can solve this. Thank you!
conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH,3),
)
conv_base.trainable = False

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
 [
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomBrightness(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomTranslation(0.2, 0.2),
]
)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_WIDTH,3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.preprocess_input(x)
x = conv_base(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)



80% could be quite decent. As for other ideas consider doing data augmentation and maybe adding more data to your dataset (I think there is quite a lot of datasets for the sentiment task all over internet).

Thank you, @JohnnyCheesecutter! I have done data augmentation. I added the data augmentation to my original question since I don't have the right to post a reply.
I have not been able to find training data for image sentiment identification. Although there is a plenty of datasets available for text sentiment classification.

You can check this datasets and models that they use.
https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/reactiongif
https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/memotion-analysis
https://paperswithcode.com/task/multimodal-sentiment-analysis
